# Not able to fetch User information from DocuSign based on EmailID

Tags: java, mule, docusignapi

I am trying to connect to DocuSign using JWT token based on OAuth.

- I am able to get the authentication token from DocuSign using JWT.
- Then, I connected DocuSign using the token and able to fetch user information using this URI (https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/userinfo) i.e. authorization is successful.
- I am not able to lookup a user using the email address. I am using below URL: 
  https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/{account_id}/users?email=users@testcorp.com

I am getting error 401 as specified below:

> HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
>   Cache-Control: no-cache
>   X-DocuSign-TraceToken: e4677d2d-88fd-4ad7-aa9e-20e1f87cc77f
>   Date: Thu, 12 Jul 2018 10:16:10 GMT
>   Content-Length: 0
>   Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains

I tried looking on the DocuSign documentation, but no success.

[Summary: Using Access token, I'm only able to fetch user information. I'm not able to call any other docuSign REST API]
Any help will be appreciated!! Thank you!!

Comment: is this reproducible? I mean, every time you get user1 - it's ok, but every time you get user2 - it's 401?

Comment: Yes, It's reproducible. We are struggling on this for a couple of days. All REST API calls using a valid access token, consistently gives 401 error.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to search for a user using the email query parameter. Please look at the API reference here - https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Users/Users/list the email query param is reserved and should not be used by API callers.
You can use the user_name_substring query param to search for users.